# Is anyone using Entity Framework in production?

Tags: entity-framework, production

I'd like to hear from people who are using EF in production, or made a valid attempt to do so.

I saw the [When NOT to use the Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517600/when-not-to-use-the-entity-framework) question on this site.  I also read [Vote of No Confidence](http://efvote.wufoo.com/forms/ado-net-entity-framework-vote-of-no-confidence/).  If you played with Entity Framework and decided not to use this, I don't want to hear from you.

I understand that EF is not mature as NHibernate or some other framework.  Unfortunately, in my company, people who make decisions don't want to use the open source projects.  Don't ask me why, because I'd like to know it myself.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882/what-real-world-usages-of-ado-net-entity-framework-do-you-know answer your question?  (It's a bit dated.)

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the link, I missed this one.  The question is very similar to mine; however, I couldn't find the answers I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we use it in production. V1 is in the field, V2 is on the way. It works really well for us so far. Did you have any other questions?

Comment: Craig, thanks.  I just started learning / playing with EF. I'm sure you'll see more question from me on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.

I'm at TechEd this week, spending a lot of time at the Entity Framework booth, and I've had lots people who are using EF in anger come up and ask me for help and advice.

Alex